# How to list all concurrent python processes in my CLI?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, process

I have opened several terminals in parallel:

```
my_name console  Jul  5 17:00  old         191
my_name ttys002  Jul  9 22:07   .        22109
my_name ttys004  Jul 10 07:17 00:04      23432
my_name ttys006  Jul  9 18:52 00:09      20880
my_name ttys007  Jul  9 18:53 00:09      20913
```

And in two of those terminals, I have launched a python file, which includes iterations, to keep the process running. 
And I would like to have the list of all python processes running. 
When I type:
`$ ps -ef | grep python` or `$ps -elf | grep python` 
I only get the current terminal:

```
501  4342  3974   0 Mer08   ??         8:59.94 /Users/my_name/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python 2021.6.944021595/languageServer.0.5.59/Microsoft.Python.LanguageServer
501 23945 22110   0  7:26   ttys002    0:00.01 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox python
```

How could I get a full list of the terminals with the associated python processes ?
My end goal is to terminate python processes using python `os.subprocess` and other libraries.

Comment: I did `ps -ef | grep python`, it gets all python processes, including root python processes. Do you happen to have a alias for `ps` ? Run `type ps` to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To view all current processes execute
>
> `ps -ax`

> `-a` flag stands for all processes
> `-x` will display all processes even those not associated with the current tty

refer [here](https://www.journaldev.com/24613/linux-ps-command)